Шифрование и хранение пароля
Допустим на на хосте #1 запущен сайт, на котором есть ЛК.
На хосте #2 запущен MySQL сервер, который хранит записи пользователей сайта.
Пользователь вводит пароль '123qwe', и отправляем запрос в БД:
SELECT NULL FROM accounts WHERE password = MD5(CONCAT((SELECT salt FROM accounts WHERE name = 'DonaldTrump'), '123qwe', 'abracadabra'))

Сможет ли злоумышленник перехватить запрос в таком виде? То есть сможет ли он увидеть все те данные, которые отправляются с Хост #1 на Хост #2?
Или стоит сначала вытаскивать соль из БД, потом шифровать на Хост #1 и в запросе отправлять уже хэш?
MySQL как-то шифрует свои запросы?

Нужно хэшировать пароль на том сервере, на котором он хранится. И тогда какие-то фентефлюхи делать не придётся........ Или сравнивать пароль тоже не стороне сервера путём применения соответствующих функций.

То есть на том, который отправляет запрос? В моем случае это Хост #1?

Хост 1 отправляет запрос на Хост 2 для проверки пользователя по паролю.... Хост 2 на своей стороне бэкенда сравнивает пароль с хэшом из БД и отдаёт ответ на Хост 1  - валидно значение или нет... Дальше Хост 1 уже делает что хочет

Так в этом то и вопрос, хост 1 должен отправить уже хэш, или введенный пароль?

Я ответ написал ещё в первом комментарии.....в первых 10-ти словах..... что из него было не ясно?

Если у вас злоумышленник каким-то образом имеет доступ к тарифику между бэкендом и субд, то зачем ему ваш пароль, если он и так все данные может видеть? В противном случае, не ясно вообще как злоумышленник может что-то там перехватить в трафике между вашими серверами. Обычно тут вопрос встает в просмотре хттп трафика между хттп-клиентом и бэкендом, но sql запросы тут никак не участвуют, сам трафик от мим защищен хттпс

И вообще если хотите нормально всё защитить, то смотрите в сторону Kerberos, иначе у вас в каком-то месте да вылезет небезопасность передачи данных.

Спасибо за прояснение ситуации.

Но вообще не нужно передавать пароль в БД. Обычно код выглядит примерно так: SELECT salt, password FROM accounts WHERE name = 'DonaldTrump'; if (md5(salt, '123wqe', 'abracadabra') == password) { // password is correct }

@AlexeyTen Да, так и сделал по сути. Дело в том, что для этого пришлось подключать модуль с реализацией шифрования. Я думал что все это дело можно возложить на MySQL, ибо тогда я не понимаю зачем вообще шифрование включили в MySQL.
